# How to query a user's session id under Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, sessionid, winlogon

Provided that there are two users, named A and B, logged on the computer, we can use command "query session" in cmd.exe to get all session ids for each user name.

My questions are as follows:

1, How can I query the session id of a given user name through API (user mode or kernel mode)?

2, How can I query the user name of a given session id through API (user mode or kernel mode)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Remote Desktop Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this.

> 1, How can I query the session id of a given user name through API
>   (user mode or kernel mode)?

Simply get all the sessions using [`WTSEnumerateSessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), iterate through them, get the user name with [`WTSQuerySessionInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check if it matches or not.

Or, if you have [an access token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_access_token_gly) for that user, you can use [`GetTokenInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the session ID for it.

> 2, How can I query the user name of a given session id through API
>   (user mode or kernel mode)?

as you might guess from the previous answer, you can use [`WTSQuerySessionInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the user name from session ID.